# Is it okay to have a table foreign key linked to 2 tables where the 2 tables are also linked

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to design a section of a system that is made up of 3 tables, entity, trust, and structure. The entity is owned by the trust and the structure is made up of entities and trusts. Do I just link the entity to the trust and then the trust to the entity or can I have the structure foreign key in both tables. Using Entity Framework update-database I am getting the following error:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Trusts_dbo.Structures_StructureId' on table 'Trusts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an entity can be owned either by a single trust or by no one - then you can introduce a foreign key OWNER pointing from entity to trust. The structure will contain 2 foreign keys - to trusts and to entities, so that entities which do not belong to any trust can still be included into a structure.